# Three-level partially nested model

Tags: r, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, lme4-nlme, nested-data

I am modeling change over time in group psychotherapy subjects using R and lme4.
My data have the following structure:

- subject (id)
- time (code 1-10 for equally spaced repeated measures)
- outcome (for every repeated measure)
- treatment (0/1 for psychotherapy/waiting list control)

My first two-level model with random slopes and intercepts works well and is simple:

```
lmer(outcome ~ time * treatment + (time | subject), data=data, REML=FALSE)
```

Now I was wondering if I should use a three-level partially nested model because the group psychotherapy subjects are nested within therapist (there where several therapist providing the treatment), but controls were non-nested. I am guessing I should account at least for main effects of therapists as argued by De Jong, Moerbeek & Van der Leeden (2010).

De Jong, K., Moerbeek, M., & Van der Leeden, R. (2010). A priori power analysis in longitudinal three-level multilevel models: an example with therapist effects. Psychotherapy Research, 20(3), 273-284.

I have found a very useful resource in the following link under "Partially nested models":
http://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer

The author gives the following code for a model virtually identical to the one I would like to test:

```
lmer(outcome ~ time * treatment + (1 | group:subject) + (0 + time | therapist:subject) + (0 + time:treatment | group) + (0 + treatment | group), data=data)
```

The data he presents is virtually identical but he adds in the model the "group" variable. I don't understand why this is because treatment/control grouping is the same as treatment/nontreatment grouping. If a subject received treatment than he is in the experimental group, if not he in the control group. How would you write this three-level partially nested model? I feel confused. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question [was eloquently answered by Thierry on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37205167).

I post his response, maybe it will be helpful for some one.

> Keep it simple. Just add a dummy therapist `none` to the subjects without therapist. Then fit the model below.
>
> ```
> lmer(outcome ~ time * treatment + (time | therapist/subject), data=data)
> ```
>
> therapist `none` is confounded with treatment `waiting list`. Therapist is a random effect and thus penalised. Treatment is a fixed effect and not penalised. Hence all information will go to the treatment effect for `waiting list` and the therapist effect for `none` will be zero.